# "Read by other session" wait event occurring in a particular Data Block of a Table

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-10g, blocking, query-performance

I'm using Oracle 10.2.0.4 with Oracle EBS R12 Application on it.

Recently we found sudden slowness in running certain Standard Concurrent Programs.

When we check from the Snap_id, we found "**User I/O**" wait with "**Read by other session**" wait event occurring on certain SQL_ID's.

From this we found a particular Data Object was causing this issue which is unfortunately a Oracle Standard table.

On further analysis we found three Data Blocks which was causing this wait event. All these Data blocks belongs to the same Data object(Table).

In such case what should we need to do ?

Comment: Can someone answer this please...

Comment: I have done a DataBase bounce. Now the issue is resolved.

But I want to know what could be the possible reason for this ?